# How to withdraw "Ready to Land" in Phabricator?

Tags: android, phabricator

How do I withdraw a Phabricator revision from "Ready to Land" status? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The revision appears in that section because it has been accepted. There are a few ways that it can leave that state:

1. You close the revision (either by landing it or by abandoning it).
2. Someone requests changes on the revision, moving the revision into the "Needs Revision" state.
3. The approver resigns from the revision, moving it back into "Needs Review" state.